# KillNode - Website not working after kill all node?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, server, port

I have a node+angular app. It was working fine. I had an issue which was `eaddrinuse 3000` . I run this command `killall node` and guess what my app which was working on `x.x.x.x:8100` is not working any more.I am using `bitvise` by the way.

This is my directory structure. I am doing this on production server.

```
    --app
     | ---assets
       ---bower_components
       ---directives
       ---home
       ---misc
       ---product
       ---services
       ---user
       ---index.html
--backend
         | ---img
           ---models
           ---node_modules
           ---public
           ---routes
           ---app.js
           ---package.json

 --package.json (frontend)
```

Comment: So... restart it?

Comment: Man,  I just looked at a different blog i made the whole directory structure wrong. Wonder why nobody did tell me.

Comment: nobody told you because directory structure in node is pretty arbitrary.  Sure there's folks that espouse one or another as "best" but there's none that are truly "wrong".